# Custom 3D graphics engine... where to plot Z coordinate

Tags: java, 3d, game-engine, cartesian-coordinates

I'm brainstorming a way to create a basic custom 3D engine by myself and it's all very new to me, as I've only practiced 2D graphics.

Assuming that we have calculations for a Z coordinate using the recommended formulas given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28043/finding-the-z-value-on-a-plane-with-x-y-values), how might I go about plotting the Z coordinate? I understand that by default, Java graphics draw on a 2D field, which means that the only coordinates I can draw to is either the X or Y coordinate... and that's where I'm stuck.

3D development is not taught in my college... so I really appreciate good feedback. The tutors here never practiced creating 3D engines, so I'm very frustrated because learning this concept is crucial.

Comment: See http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/routines/3d_to_2d.htm

Comment: Are you using any kind of API like OpenGL or are you more after the theoretical side of how you'd render within a 2D canvas?

Comment: Alex T., I'm after the theoretical side of rendering within a 2D canvas.

Comment: @Andrew Probably included in some of your main search topics should be 3D projection (starting with orthographic and working your way to perspective), raytracing, and scanline rasterization. I actually recommend it in that order with scanline rasterization being last (somewhat unusual), because raytracing is still a widely studied subject with plenty of resources. Scanline rasterization has become dominated by the GPU doing all the grunt work and it's hard to find people still implementing scanline rasterizers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to map 3D coordinates to a 2D plane (the screen) you'll need to understand the concept of the Frustum and how to utilize a Projection Matrix.

[image: Frustum in 3D space with near and far clipping planes]

[This article](http://schabby.de/projection-matrix/) does an excellent job of explaining what it does and how to implement one.  Writing your own engine for this seems to be a massive undertaking and assumes you understand the vector and matrix mathematics.  If not, I would suggest doing some reading on linear algebra; it's fundamental to this kind of programming.

If you'd like to work with some already established technologies, look into [OpenGL for Java](http://opengl.j3d.org/).

Comment: I've never seen this API before; is it distinct from JOGL?

Comment: @AlexT. Nope: "most of the information you'll find here will be related to JOGL"

Answer (score 0):

I know how to make a 3d program in English but not in code.
If you would like to make one, please let me know. So I can see how active you are.

Oh my apologies. I didn't answer*. Let me elaborate on your predicament.

Z axis doesn't exist. It's an illusion. You need to produce a procedural code to establish this illusion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)